# Why are c++ .dll not recognized in bin folder of asp.net webapp?

Tags: asp.net, dll, dllimport, bin, vs-web-application-project

I create an ASP.NET Webapp with Razor syntax in Visual Studio 2015, in C#.

I have to use 20 third party native c++ dll files (most of them for image handing, libtiff-5.dll, libpng16-16.dll, etc...).

Even when I manually copy those dll files into the bin folder, the app would not run. The error is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'managedDllWrapper.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

But according to almost all hints in the internet, copying to bin folder should work.

When I copy the dlls into the C:\Windows folder, the webapp runs perfectly, but only locally on my machine.

Also, when I create a C# Console app, instead of a webapp, copying into the bin folder works fine.

Why doesn't it work for a webapp? How can I import those dlls?

- I cannot reference them into Visual Studio to the project, as they are not a valid COM assembly.
- the dlls are not imported in the code with dllimport, as I don't know the specific functions they provide. A managed dll wrapper uses the dlls.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What type of web application are you creating?  And what version of .NET Framework are you using in the web application?

Comment: I use .NET 4.0, and the web application should be a single page application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the problem one to one, but I circumvented the problem successfully:

By rewriting the c#/c++ wrapper with explicit dllimport, I adressed the dll files directly with path. Then, the dependent dll just have to be in the same folder as the referenced dll. This works also in web apps.